# Import C dll function in python

Tags: python, c, dll

Which data type should be used in this **stringUpcase** function in my DLL file

```
void __cdecl stringUpcase(char IN_str[], char OUT_str[], int32_t len);
```

I am trying ctype.c_char_p in Python 3.6 and This function should return the uppercase string "HELO" in OUT_str variable.

```
dl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("path/of/dll/file.dll")

IN_str = 'helo'
OUT_str = ''
IN_len = len(IN_str)

dl.stringUpcase.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
dl.stringUpcase.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int32]

dl.stringUpcase(IN_str, OUT_str, IN_len);
```

Console error output is

```
 line 21, in <module>
    dl.stringUpcase(IN_str, OUT_str, IN_len);
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: `strCnt` or `stringUpcase`?

Comment: sorry my mistake ... It is **stringUpcase** function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass python string as an argument of type `c_char_p`. Python3 unlike python2 is pretty strict about typing in ctypes.

The working sample would look like this.

```py
import ctypes

ins = ctypes.c_char_p(b'helo') 
lens = len(ins.value)
outs = ctypes.create_string_buffer(lens+1)
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./upper.so")

lib.stringUpcase.restype = None
lib.stringUpcase.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int32]

lib.stringUpcase(ins, outs, lens)

print(outs.value)
```

Pay attention to the fact that `c_char_p` points to a zero-terminated string, so `len` argument is redundant here. Moreover to construct `c_char_p` you need to pass bytes object or and integer address rather than just a string, to be able to use string as an argument you need to use `c_wchar_p` type and `wchar_t*` in your library respectively.

One more thing to pay attention to is the fact that your `C` function does not allocate memory so you need for `outs` to be large enough to contain the result.

Comment: Thank you it works really good, but the output is **b'HELO'** and I would like to transform it back to "python" **string**. so the result will be only **HELO** How is it possible?

Comment: @MichalMarcin decode them in some encoding, like this `print(outs.value.decode('ascii'))`